# Why Are The Network Files Changing? - Can't Connect To WiFi After Reboot

Tags: wifi, pi-zero

I am configuring my Zero to connect to wifi in advance.
My steps are:

- Format SD card with SDFormatter
- Burn Raspbian Jessie with Win32DiskImager
- Mount the SDCard in Windows with Paragon ExtFs For Windows
- Modify /etc/network/interfaces

`auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

- Modify /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

`network={
   ssid="my network name"
   psk="my network password"
   proto=RSN
   key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
   pairwise=CCMP
   auth_alg=OPEN
}`

- Connect a wifi dongle via OTG
- Power on via USB cable to the laptop
- Find the IP with SoftPerfect NetworkScanner
- ssh in with Putty
- Reboot with `sudo reboot now`

After waiting a few minutes to reboot I can no longer find the IP on my network scanner.

Unplugging and reboot has no effect either.

I have done it several times and each time I start for the first time I can ssh in (and even VNC in). However, as soon as I restart I can't connect.

Is there a log somewhere of the boot process to help understand why the second boot doesn't connect to wifi but the first does?

EDIT: Following the comments I checked the files again. This morning they were both full of NULLs (binary?) so I changed them to the new setup as mentioned by @Milliways.

I restarted, connected to wifi, did `sudo reboot now` and the following was in wpa_supplicant:

```
:38 raspberrypi dhcpcd[436]: dev: loaded udev
May 22 04:22:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started getty on tty2-tty6 if dbus and
```

And the following was in the interfaces file:

```
: Starting system-ifup.slice.
May 22 04:22:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Created slice system-ifup.slice.
May 22 04:22:38 raspberrypi console-setup[264]: Setting up console font and keymap...done.
May 22 04:22:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Set console font and keymap.
May 22 04:22:38 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[372]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
May 22 04:22:38 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[373]: wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID 'RHAP1'
May 22 04:22:38 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[373]: wlan0: Associated with 00:1e:13:1c:04:30
May 22 04:22:38
```

Why is my Pi logging to the configuration files???

Comment: Can you check the sd card after reboot with your Windows PC,  to see if your changes have been undermined by the Pi after a reboot?

Comment: What you have would have been unreliable under Wheezy and is obsolete on Jessie (although it may work if the network was available at boot). You should do it in a more robust manner. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)